# Translate CGBitmapContextCreate from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-graphics, swift4

```
unsigned char pixelData[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
    1,
    1,
    bitsPerComponent,
    bytesPerRow,
    colorSpace,
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
```

I want to translate `unsigned char pixelData[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };` to Swift. It seems I have to use `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. But I do not know how.

Comment: see the [__Apple Docs__](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer) for further info, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a native Swift array and then call its `withUnsafeMutableBytes` method to get an `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` to the array's storage. The `baseAddress` property then gets you the address of the buffer as an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`.

Here's an example:

```
import CoreGraphics

var pixelData: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
pixelData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { pointer in
    guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.displayP3),
        let context = CGContext(data: pointer.baseAddress,
                                width: 1,
                                height: 1,
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: 4,
                                space: colorSpace,
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    else {
        return
    }
    // Draw a white background
    context.setFillColor(CGColor.white)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
}

print(pixelData) // prints [255, 255, 255, 255]
```

Note that the pointer is only valid inside the closure you pass to `withUnsafeMutableBytes`. Since the graphics context assumes this pointer is valid for the duration of the context's lifetime, returning the context from the closure and accessing it from the outside would be undefined behavior.

As you can see, however, the contents of the `pixelData` array have been changed when `withUnsafeMutableBytes` returns.